# Asynchronous code (javascript's setTimeout equivalent) in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

What would be a nim equivalent of this javascript program with setTimeout? Please don't hack with sleep(1000) and keep the code asynchronous.

```
setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        console.log("Hello world")
    },
    1000
)
```

Answer (score 6):

The asyncdispatch module defines a `sleepAsync` function: https://nim-lang.org/docs/asyncdispatch.html#sleepAsync,int

You can use that to create a `setTimeout` equivalent.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that setTimeout is not a language primitive, but rather a runtime primitive, provided by whichever runloop implementation you're using. E.g. if you're writing a command line tool (or a server), then Nim's asyncdispatch may be your choice and like @dom96 said, you can use sleepAsync. If you're writing a GUI app, the timers should be provided by your underlying platform SDK.